# NaN при поиске максимального элемента в массиве

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему при использовании Math.max у массива выходным значением даёт NaN?

```
const graphValues = [
{
    'AB': 3,
    'AC': 8
},
{
    'BC': 4,
    'BD': 3
},
{
    'CB': 4,
    'CE': 5
},
{'ED': 3},
{'DF': 3}
] 

for (let i = 0; i < graphValues.length; i++) {
    let value = graphValues[i]
    let maxValue = Math.max(Object.values(value))
    console.log(Object.values(value))
    console.log(maxValue)
}
```

В консоли:

```
(2) [3, 8]
NaN
app.js:50
(2) [4, 3]
NaN
app.js:50
(2) [4, 5]
NaN
app.js:50
(1) [3]
3
app.js:50
(1) [3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Правильно будет так:

```
Math.max(...Object.values(value))
//       ^^^
```

Т.к. `Math.max` принимает на вход **не массив значений**, а неограниченное количество параметров в виде чисел, т.е. не `[1,5,8]`,  а `1,5,8`

Comment: Спасибо большое